# Find commutator $[P_\mu,K_\nu]$ in conformal group

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

We have conformal group with next element of this group:

$$U=e^{i(P_\mu\epsilon^\mu-\frac{1}{2}M_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\mu\nu}+\rho D+\epsilon_\mu K^\mu)},$$

where $D$ is dilatation operator
$$x^\mu\rightarrow e^{-\rho}x^\mu$$

$K_\mu$ is special conformal transformation operator

$$x^\mu \rightarrow \frac{x^\mu+c^\mu x^2}{1+2cx+c^2x^2}$$

I am trying to calculate the next commutator:

$$[P_\mu,K_\nu]$$

I am already know that it equals to $2i(g_{\mu\nu}D+M_{\mu\nu})$ from different sources on groups, but a have not found proof of this equation. For other commutators in this group we can do next trick

$$U^{-1}U^\prime Ux^\mu=U^{\prime\prime}x^\mu,$$

For example,

$$(I,0,\rho,0)^{-1}(I,0,0,c)(I,0,\rho,0)x^\mu=\frac{x^\mu+c^\mu e^{-\rho}x^2}{1+2ce^{-\rho} x+c^2e^{-2\rho} x^2}=(I,0,0,e^{-\rho}c)x^\mu$$

so

$$e^{-i\rho D}K^\mu e^{i\rho D}=e^{-\rho}K^\mu$$

and

$$[D,K^\mu]=-iK^\mu$$

But for $[P_\mu,K_\nu]$ I cannot find how to calculate it. It is proposed that similar procedure could help. I tried to start from various $U$, but I don't understand how to obtain $D$ and $M$ on the right side. If I try to calculate directly, then I have, for example

$$(I,a,0,0)^{-1}(I,0,0,c)(I,a,0,0)x^\mu=(I,\frac{a^\mu+c^\mu a^2}{1+2ac+a^2c^2}-a,0,c)x^\mu$$

$$e^{-i\epsilon P}(1+ic^\mu K_\mu) e^{i\epsilon P}=(1+i(\frac{\epsilon^\mu+c^\mu \epsilon^2}{1+2\epsilon c+\epsilon^2c^2}-a)P_\mu)(1+ic^\mu K_\mu)$$

Also I tried to use other commutation relations, but I have not found how it could help.

It would be nice if someone find how to calculate the commutator using appropriate choice of $U$ and maybe other commutation relations, but any other ideas would be nice too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to work with generators rather than group elements. The generators have a representation in real space, that is $P_\mu = -i\partial_\mu, D = -i x^{\mu} \partial_\mu, M_{\mu\nu} = i(x^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}-x_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}), K_{\mu} = -i(2x_{\mu}x^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}-x^2\partial_\mu)$. See Eq.(4.18) of Di Francesco's book. Then one can compute the commutators of these vector fields, see Eq.(4.19).

Comment: This works, but I have a "minus" in the answer when I use these definitions of generators. I guess this is because Di Francesco use "$-b^\mu$" instead of "$+c^\mu$"